# list users that are not part of a few distribution lists PowerShell Exchange online

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm looking to find users whos primary smtp is our domain.com that are not part of certain office365 distribution lists we have. For example Dist1, Dist2, Dist3, Dist4. I'm not very good with PowerShell but I found this script and I'm hoping someone can help me adjust this.

This script pulls the group membership of all groups.

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain.com"} | ForEach-Object {
    $user   = Get-User -Identity $_.DistinguishedName                      
    $groups = Get-Group | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $User}
    $_ | Select-Object DisplayName, Alias, PrimarySMTPAddress,
                       @{Name = 'Groups' ; Expression = {$groups.Name -join '; '}}
} | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\O365UserGroups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does `$user` have a "memberof" property?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script that checks if users whos primary smtp is your domain.com and if they are members of distributionsgroup 1 or 2. If the user is not a member of a distributionsgroup it will output this. You can add export to csv etc easily yourself.

```
$Users = Get-Mailbox | ? {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like "*domain.com"} #Enter your domain
$DistributionGroups = @("dist1","dist2") #Enter names of your distributiongroups

foreach($DistributionGroup in $DistributionGroups)
{ 
    $DistributionGroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember $DistributionGroup
    
    foreach($User in $Users)
    {
        foreach($DistributionGroupMember in $DistributionGroupMembers)
        {
            if($DistributionGroupMember.PrimarySmtpAddress -ne $User.PrimarySmtpAddress)
            {
                Write-Host "$($User.PrimarySmtpAddress) missing in $DistributionGroup" #Export output here fx. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```